# Как получить погодные данные от ближайшей погодной станции?

Tags: java, android, weather

Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста. Есть список погодных станций с заданными координатами широты и долготы:

```
<station>
<station_id>KJKL</station_id>
<state>KY</state>
<station_name>Julian Carroll Airport</station_name>
<latitude>37.6</latitude>
<longitude>-83.32</longitude>
<html_url>http://weather.noaa.gov/weather/current/KJKL.html</html_url>
<rss_url>http://weather.gov/xml/current_obs/KJKL.rss</rss_url>
<xml_url>http://weather.gov/xml/current_obs/KJKL.xml</xml_url>
</station>

<station>
<station_id>KLEX</station_id>
<state>KY</state>
<station_name>Lexington, Blue Grass Airport</station_name>
<latitude>38.05</latitude>
<longitude>-84.6</longitude>
<html_url>http://weather.noaa.gov/weather/current/KLEX.html</html_url>
<rss_url>http://weather.gov/xml/current_obs/KLEX.rss</rss_url>
<xml_url>http://weather.gov/xml/current_obs/KLEX.xml</xml_url>
</station>

...
```

и т.д. Их около полтысячи. Как мне определить ближайшую станцию по отношению к Андроид устройству?  Я знаю, как сделать парсинг погоды, определить местонахождние для устройства(по формуле), сравнить с конкретной станцией. Но их там полтысячи! То есть нужно автоматически определить ближайшую станцию.

Comment: Через это пробовали? http://openweathermap.org/current

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужно:

1. Получить координаты устройства.
2. Создать список/массив для хранения квадратного корня из суммы квадратов координат каждой станции по обеим осям относительно вашего положения.
3. Отсортируйте полученный список от большего к меньшему.
4. Теперь у вас в списке первый элемент - ближайшая станция.

Comment: Спасибо, понял!

Answer (score 3):

Давненько я решал очень похожую задачу, на определения ближайшей точки по гео:координатам, относительно своего device, но я находил именно расстояние. Возможно в android есть иные реализации, но я просто не работал в этом направлении а пока вот:

```
class Solution {
public static double distance(String longA, String latA, String longB, String latB) // Растояние м-у 2-я точками зная их координаты
{
    double longARad = Double.parseDouble(longA) * Math.PI / 180d;
    double latARad = Double.parseDouble(latA) * Math.PI / 180d;
    double longBRad = Double.parseDouble(longB) * Math.PI / 180d;
    double latBRad = Double.parseDouble(latB) * Math.PI / 180d;

    double x = (longBRad - longARad) * Math.cos((latARad + latBRad) / 2d);
    double y = latBRad - latARad;

    return Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y) * 6371; // Умножаем на ср. показатель радиуса Земли, для перевода в метрическую систему.
}
public static void main(String args[]) 
{
    String bestStation = null;
    double bestDist = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        double distance = distance(longitude1, latitude1, longitude2, latitude2); // используем метод distance
        if (distance < bestDist) // находим ближайшую станцию
        {
            bestDist = distance;
            bestStation = station[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println(bestStation );
  }
}
```

Я загружал сюда, больше 5000 адресов, причем мне приходилось, ещё форматировать предварительно адрес из БД, так как у меня не было чистых значений как в Вашем примере, а просто String с кучей лишних значений и работало отлично и очень быстро.

Comment: Спасибо! Я так понимаю, мне нужно сделать парсинг всех станции, положить значения в коллекцию, определить текущее положение и методом distance в цикле проверять ближайшую дистанцию. Такой вопрос - в какую коллекцию лучше положить данные longitute и latitude станиции?

Comment: Я не знаю нюансов, если станции стационарны, то может не имеет смысла постоянно парсить их, а выделить для них немного памяти и сохранить, создать сервис, который будет в отдельном потоке, проверять наличие новых станций и просить добавить их в память. И уже с памяти спокойно будете тягать longitute и latitude, а вот какой ресурс использовать я не могу посоветовать, здесь мнения могут разойтись. Поэтому просто опишите ваш вопрос еще раз, в новой теме. люди будут рады ответить)